# how to detect rotated objects in an image with RCNN?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, object-detection

I want to train an **RCNN** object detector in **matlab** to detect multiple objects in an image like faces, vehicles, etc. But some the objects have different angles in the image. How should I draw ROI rectangles when using `trainRCNNObjectDetector`? Should I rotate the image for every object?